# Custom Validator validation not firing for textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="textbox_width_height" 
placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
      Enabled="true" ValidateEmptyText="true" SetFocusOnError="true"
      OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_OnServerValidate"   
       ControlToValidate="txtDOB" 
       ErrorMessage="Age must be grater than 16 years"  >
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

and here is the event

```
protected void CustomValidator1_OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        DateTime todayDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        DateTime textDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);

        DateTime total = todayDate.AddYears(-16);
        if (textDOB <= total)
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: code looks ok i hope you wired event correcly...check you autowire on page property is not false and if it is flase you attached event properly

Comment: yea the code is ok I test it is validating. Or you want to validate it in real time ?

Answer (score 2):

Place AutopostBack="True" it will become something like this

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="textbox_width_height" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: that should not be case because on button click it will fire validation even autopostback is not false